# Arithmetic overflow occurred. when Executing a Stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sybase

**Hi There 
I have below stored Proc**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.glextract_branch_audit_figures (@fin_period DATETIME, @runtime VARCHAR(1))
AS 

BEGIN

declare @branch INT
declare @debtor_open_balance money
declare @debtor_theo_balance money
declare @debtor_close_balance money
declare @stock_open_balance money
declare @stock_close_balance money
declare @mtd_goods_in money
declare @mtd_goods_out money
declare @mtd_adjustments money
declare @mtd_sales money
declare @stock_theo_balance money

SELECT @branch = branch FROM branch_control

SELECT @debtor_open_balance = debtor_balance, @stock_open_balance = (stock_balance - stock_ind_bf + stock_onrepr_bf) FROM period_control WHERE fin_period = @fin_period

SELECT @debtor_theo_balance = @debtor_open_balance + (SELECT SUM(doc_amt) from cf_debtor_transaction WHERE tran_type IN 
          (4002, 4004, 4050, 4052, 4099, 4101, 4102, 4103, 4104, 4105, 4106, 4107, 4108, 4109, 4110, 4111, 4112, 4113, 4114, 4115,         
               4118, 4119, 4123, 4201, 4204, 4211, 4212, 4220, 4225, 4227, 4229, 4232, 4240, 4241, 4243, 4244, 4248, 4249, 4250, 4251, 4275, 
           4300, 4423, 4502, 4551, 4552, 4599, 4601, 4602, 4603, 4604, 4605, 4606, 4607, 4608, 4609, 4611, 4612, 4613, 4614, 4615, 4616, 
           4620, 4621, 4702, 4703, 4704, 4705, 4706, 4707, 4708, 4709, 4710, 4711, 4712, 4713, 4713, 4714, 4715, 4716, 4717, 4718, 4719, 
           4720, 4721, 4722, 4723, 4724, 4725, 4726, 4727, 4728, 4740, 4741, 4742, 4743, 4744, 4750, 4751, 4774, 4777) 
           AND fin_period = @fin_period)

SELECT @debtor_close_balance = SUM(dbo.cf_acc_balance(account_guid)) FROM account

SELECT @stock_close_balance = SUM((sh.qty_on_hand - sh.qty_on_ind + sh.qty_on_repair) * a.cost) FROM stock_holding  sh, all_sku_costs a WHERE a.sku = sh.sku

SELECT @mtd_goods_in = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN tran_type IN (7215, 7225, 7715, 7717, 7718, 7805, 7405, 7705, 7707, 7708) THEN 0 ELSE cost * qty END),0)
                FROM stock_transaction 
                WHERE tran_type IN (7015, 7035, 7045, 7105, 7115, 7125, 7185, 7135, 7145, 7155, 7205, 7215, 7225, 7235,
                    7245, 7255, 7265, 7275, 7285, 7295, 7405, 7415, 7445, 7455, 7465, 7475, 7485, 7495,
                    3502, 4599, 7955, 7305, 7335, 7175, 7195)
                AND fin_period = @fin_period

SELECT @mtd_goods_out = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN tran_type IN (7215, 7225, 7715, 7717, 7718, 7805, 7405, 7705, 7707, 7708) THEN 0 ELSE (cost * qty) * -1 END),0) 
                FROM stock_transaction 
                WHERE tran_type IN (7505, 7515, 7535, 7605, 7615, 7625, 7685, 7635, 7645, 7655, 7665, 7705, 7715, 7725,
                    7735, 7745, 7755, 7765, 7795, 7805, 7815, 7845, 7855, 7865, 7885, 7895, 7875, 7925,
                    3001, 3002, 4099, 7956, 7775, 7935, 7675, 7695)                 
                AND fin_period = @fin_period

SELECT @mtd_adjustments = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN tran_type IN (7717,7718,7707,7708) THEN 0
                    ELSE CASE WHEN tran_type IN (7018,7048,7718,7829,7868) THEN (cost * qty) * -1
                    ELSE (cost * qty) END END),0)
                FROM stock_transaction 
                WHERE tran_type in (7017, 7018, 7037, 7038, 7047, 7048, 7107, 7108, 7117, 7118, 7127, 7128, 7137, 7138,
                    7147, 7148, 7207, 7208, 7217, 7218, 7227, 7228, 7427, 7437, 7447, 7448, 7497, 7507,
                    7508, 7517, 7518, 7537, 7538, 7647, 7648, 7707, 7708, 7717, 7718, 7828, 7838, 7868,
                    7898, 7438, 7417, 7818, 7957, 7958, 7967, 7968, 7428, 7438, 7829, 7839)
                AND fin_period = @fin_period

SELECT @mtd_sales = ISNULL(SUM(cost * -1),0) FROM debtor_transaction WHERE tran_type IN (4002,4502) AND fin_period = @fin_period   

SELECT @stock_theo_balance = @stock_open_balance + @mtd_goods_in + @mtd_goods_out + @mtd_adjustments + @mtd_sales                                           

 IF (@runtime = 'E')
 BEGIN 
     TRUNCATE TABLE GL_WK_BRANCH_AUDIT_FIGURES
    INSERT INTO GL_WK_BRANCH_AUDIT_FIGURES


 SELECT
    @fin_period as Period,
    @branch as BranchCode,
    ISNULL(@debtor_open_balance,0) as DebtorsOpening,
    ISNULL(@debtor_close_balance,0) as DebtorsClosing,
    ISNULL(@stock_open_balance,0) as StockOpening,
    ISNULL(@stock_close_balance,0) as StockClosing,
    ISNULL(@debtor_theo_balance,0) - ISNULL(@debtor_close_balance,0) as DebtorsDiff,
    ISNULL(@stock_theo_balance,0) - ISNULL(@stock_close_balance,0) as StockDiff
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
 TRUNCATE TABLE GL_BRANCH_AUDIT_FIGURES
 INSERT INTO GL_BRANCH_AUDIT_FIGURES
    SELECT
    @fin_period as Period,
    @branch as BranchCode,
    ISNULL(@debtor_open_balance,0) as DebtorsOpening,
    ISNULL(@debtor_close_balance,0) as DebtorsClosing,
    ISNULL(@stock_open_balance,0) as StockOpening,
    ISNULL(@stock_close_balance,0) as StockClosing,
    ISNULL(@debtor_theo_balance,0) - ISNULL(@debtor_close_balance,0) as DebtorsDiff,
    ISNULL(@stock_theo_balance,0) - ISNULL(@stock_close_balance,0) as StockDiff
    END
END
```

**I tried to execute the proc as shown below, passing the fin period and runtime parameter**

```
execute dbo.glextract_branch_audit_figures'2018-08-05', 'E'
```

However, it is giving me the: Arithmetic overflow occurred error

I have a stock transaction_table that has a field called doc_amt with a big amount.
if I change this amount to something smaller it doesn't crash with the above error.

Please see the value on stock_transaction below:

refer on the procedure above

```
SELECT @mtd_goods_out
```

[image]

Comment: What is the datatype of doc_amt column?

Comment: @SalmanA datatype is money

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size of a money datatype is listed here - if you breach that size you will get an artithmetic overflow. Your only alternative is to use a specific numeric datatype instead which allows larger sizes:

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1600/doc/html/san1393050391020.html